# Spark incorrectly deserializes object during Dataset.map

Tags: apache-spark

I am calling the Spark Dataset API via JVM interop in Clojure. Below is the Clojure code and corresponding Scala code.

`not_working.clj`

```clj
(ns erp12.clark-example.repro2
  (:gen-class)
  (:import (org.apache.spark.sql SparkSession)
           (org.apache.spark.sql Encoders)
           (scala Function1)
           (java.io Serializable)))

(defn -main
  [& _]
  (-> (SparkSession/builder)
      (.master "local[*]")
      (.getOrCreate)
      (.range 1)
      (.map (reify
              Function1
              (apply [_ row]
                row)
              Serializable)
            (Encoders/LONG))
      (.show)))
```

`working.scala`

```scala
package com.nortia_solutions.ppi

import java.lang.Long
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoders, SparkSession}

case object Play extends App {
  SparkSession
    .builder
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
    .range(1)
    .map(new Function[Long, Long] with Serializable {
      def apply(v1: Long): Long = v1
    })(Encoders.LONG)
    .show()
}
```

The Scala code works as expected, but the Clojure code throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda to field org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.f of type scala.Function3 in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
```

The full stack trace can be found in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/erp12/233a60574dc157aa544079959108f9db).

The exception is **not** raised (and `-main` behaves correctly) when:

- `not_working.clj` is compiled into an uberjar.
- or `-main` is called in a REPL.

The exception is raised when:

- Running `clj -X:spark erp12.clark-example.repro2/-main`
- Running `-main` via a test runner

It seems that, depending on the context, the Spark deserializer is improperly deserializing a `Function3` as a `SerializedLambda`. Why is this happening?